# Proper ways/strategies of observing and transforming ODE / PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I encountered with a lot of problem about ODE, many of which needs a proper observing or transforming before continuing, but to me, seeking the "key" out is very hard, for an observing example:

> We consider the following ordinary differential equation:
> $$\begin{cases}x''(t)+x(t)+x(t)^3=0,\\(x(0),x'(0))=(x_0,0),\end{cases}$$
> where $x(t)$ takes values in $\mathbb R$. Prove that for all $x_0 \in\mathbb R$, the solution of the above system is periodic.

I didn't manage to solve it first, but after a hint namely "Observe that $E(t):=\frac{1}{2}x'(t)^2+\frac{1}{2}x(t)^2+\frac{1}{4}x(t)^4$ is conserved" this problem becomes very easy, but this observation is very hard to me. For another transforming example:

> Solve the following ordinary differential equation
> $$x\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{x^6-y^2}+3y$$

I spent a large amount of time observing this problem and finally figured out that we should take $g(x):=\frac{y(x)}{x^3}$ and this problem will reduce to a much simpler form. (a hint says this can be solved by integration, but I didn’t figure it out) But observing or transforming the proper thing takes a large amount of time and sometimes need something like "AHA" moment. So my question is, are there any "good strategies" that we should know of observing or transforming an ODE/PDE?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

That first one is not that bad; in particular you have probably seen $x''+x=0$ before, which has the same basic feature. Basically if there's a periodic solution then there must be a conserved quantity, and the way to go look for that in a "force balance" type equation is to multiply by $x'$ and integrate in time, or equivalently to do a vector line integral over a trajectory in space.

Once you have the conserved quantity, you have periodicity if the level set is closed and contains no equilibrium points (and the solutions are unique).  The generalization of that to multidimensional systems is $x''+\nabla F(x)=0$, in which case $F$ is the conserved quantity. This is a relatively general strategy with physical meaning, so it is worth keeping it in mind.

The second one is a little bit contrived, I think, but one motivation for that substitution comes from thinking about dimensional analysis. If $x$ and $y$ both have units then $y$ must be $x^3 g(x)$ for some dimensionless $g$ just so that $x^6-y^2$ makes sense. This will at least simplify the square root. The fact that the problem in terms of $x$ and $g$ turns out to be separable seems like an artifact of the problem "design" to me, rather than being especially general. Nor does it seem obvious that this will happen at a first glance.

Personally I don't think it is worth actively developing the skill of "getting into the head of the problem author", even though it can help you in coursework, competitions, etc.

Sadly I can't give much completely general advice; differential equations as a subject is full of "pockets" where a strategy helps in that pocket and nowhere else.